# Better way to fetch JSON data from a server from iOS app

Tags: objective-c, json, ios, coldfusion, server

I have successfully coded a network request to fetch JSON data from our server. The remote function is written in ColdFusion. However, the code is quite lengthy and involved. I also noticed in the API there are other seemingly very similar ways one can go about making network requests, such as `NSURLSession`. (I know `NSURLConnection` will be deprecated in the future, replaced by `NSURLSession`.) I would like to know what is the best way to make a network request - using modern code that is not going to be deprecated in the near future. Is `NSURLSession` the best way to go?

Here are my requirements:

- Fetch JSON data from a function in a .cfc file on the server
- Must be secure
- Must be able to perform error checking
- Only need to support iOS 7+
- Preferably more concise code

Here is my current and lengthy code, using several variables, `NSMutableURLRequest`, and `NSURLConnection`:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Q", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSInteger success = 1;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:MYURL];
    NSData *postData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"method=methodName&username=%@&password=%@", usernameVar, passwordVar] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *requestError = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                            returningResponse:&response
                                                        error:&requestError];

    //if communication was successful
    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300) {
        NSError *serializeError = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error:&serializeError];
        success = [jsonData[@"ERROR"] integerValue];

        if (success == 0) {
            //success! do stuff with the jsonData dictionary here
        }
        else {
            //handle ERROR from server
        }
    }
    else {
        //handle error for unsuccessful communication with server
    }
});
```

Could you help me clean this up to be implemented the most preferred way for modern apps of today?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSURLSession` was designed from the ground up to be as similar to `NSURLConnection` as possible, so that those accustomed to using the latter will have no problem transitioning to the former.  Meanwhile, `NSURLSession` has a lot of major advantages over `NSURLConnection`.

First of all, we can get rid of all the code for dispatching on a background thread.  `NSURLSession` works on background threads automatically unless we specify otherwise.

We still have to create our `NSURLRequest`.  I don't know any way around this.

But once we've got our request set up, and remember, all of this is outside the GCD block, we just do this:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // do stuff

}] resume];
```

As you can see, it's quite similar to `NSURLConnection`.  We replace `// do stuff` with the stuff we want to do when the request is complete (completion handler).  We have our data, our response, and our error all in this block.

A lot of the new power from `NSURLSession` comes from the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object.  Using `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, we can easily set up downloads/uploads to happen in the background (when our app is not open).  We can specify to only run on Wi-Fi and not use cellular data as setting a BOOL.  We can set a BOOL to tell the OS to only try doing our background uploads/downloads when the device is on Wi-Fi and plugged into a power source.

`NSURLSessionConfiguration` also has an `HTTPAdditionalHeaders` property, which is an `NSDictionary` object containing additional headers that should be sent with requests using this configuration.

There's a lot more information about [`NSURLSessionConfiguration` here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/ephemeralSessionConfiguration).